# 3D text not rendering in three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

The text 'Hello three.js!' is not rendering in my scene. It worked fine when I was using BoxGeometry but I seem to missing something for TextBufferGeometry.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); // fov, aspect, near and far
camera.position.set(-15, 0, 25);
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30 } );

  var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
    font: font,
    size: 80,
    height: 5,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    material: 0,
    extrudeMaterial: 1
  } );

  textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
  textGeo.computeVertexNormals();

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, material );

  scene.add(mesh);

} );

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add(light);


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

I can't make sense of three.js documenation for `TextGeometry` https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/TextGeometry

[image]

Comment: You're trying to load this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json Do you actually have that file in a `fonts` folder?

Comment: @ChrisG yes I do. Have updated post with image of file structure. I can `console.log(font)` and get `font ee {data: Object}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to move the render code inside the font loader callback.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); // fov, aspect, near and far
camera.position.set(-15, 0, 25);
camera.lookAt( scene.position );

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30 } );

  var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
    font: font,
    size: 80,
    height: 5,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 10,
    bevelSize: 8,
    bevelSegments: 5
  } );

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

  scene.add(mesh);

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
  light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
  scene.add(light);


  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

} );
```

Comment: well done ) Just out of curiousity, why don't you use a render loop?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the render loop. Haven't got that far yet

Comment: it's not so difficult ) Have a look at the `render` function [here](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/hm7azyfu/)

Comment: What's the advantage of having the render called more than once?

Comment: You won't bump into the problem from your question )

Comment: Are there any issues with performance continuously rendering the scene?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147895/discussion-between-prisoner849-and-stretch0).